# Please Explain to me this kotlin statement?

Tags: kotlin, label, this

Please explain to me what does this mean (this@A.address) and thank you.

```
class A(val address: String) {

 inner class B(telephone: String) {

 fun printAddress() = println(this@A.address)

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

`this@A` is called a qualified this, and it is shortly documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html).

`this@A` is used to access the outer object of type `A`.
Because `B` is an inner class, instances of `B` have to be created using an instance of the enclosing class `A`, the instance of `A` used than is accessed through `this@A`.
Thus `this@A.address` is the field `address` of the instance of class `A` used to create the current instance of class `B`.